# Jquery-UI button icon without text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want use jquery-ui button with text on them. I am using the HTML javascript jquery-ui code below, but the icons display without any text on the button, only when I hold the mouse button on it, it displays the  included text. How can I fix it so I can have the text displayed next to the icons.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Button - Icons</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#but1" ).button({
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-locked"
      },
      text: false 
    });


    $( "#but2" ).button({
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-clock"
      },
      text: false
    });




  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="but1" value="Rest">Button with icon only</button>
<button id="but2" value="Rest">Button with icon only</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Text is not displayed because you have written

```
$( "#but1" ).button({
  icons:{
    primary: "ui-icon-clock"
  },
  text: false
});
```

try below code

```
$("#but1").button({
    icons: { secondary: "ui-icon-locked" }
});
```

it will display both text and icon.

Comment: Hi debin, I tried it like you say, remove the text:false and change primary to secondary, but it shows the samething, button with icons and no text, and when hold mouse over shows the text.

Comment: Hi debin, sorry I did not check it well, yes it works with your suggestion, thank you very much.